# TYPO3 - overwrite styles on a single page

Tags: css, typo3

How to overwrite some styles on a specified site?
I would like to do it the css-file way.

Still no answer below works in my case..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the amount of CSS to apply, you could also consider to just [add the page ID as a class on the `<body>`](http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/cool-stuff-typoscript/body-page-id.html), e.g. `<body class="uid-456">`:

```
page.bodyTag >
page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
page.bodyTagCObject {
    field = uid
    wrap = <body class="uid-|">
}
```

Then, in your CSS:

```
.uid-456 myElement {
    myCustomStyle... /* Applies to page ID = 456 only. */
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
Tested with Templavoilà. The following worked (From the `Setup` field of the main template):

```
page = PAGE
page {
    typeNum = 0

    10 = USER
    10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page

    bodyTag >
    bodyTagCObject = TEXT
    bodyTagCObject {
        field = uid
        wrap = <body class="uid-|">
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: that was the biggest surprise evert.. that typo3 don't add page ids to the body for default.
ok but also, is the tsconfig field the right places for your code?

Comment: @Sven Koluem No, this will go in the template record ("Setup") for the site since this is site-wide (i.e., the page ID will be added to all pages - you can apply CSS as needed).

Comment: pasted it inside the tsconfig field -> @ the page options.
saved it -> refresehd it -> looked at the source code ..
there was no id added.

Comment: +1 beautieful solution. @Sven, if you make changes in typoscript cache needs to be cleared.

Comment: Do not enter this as PageTS in the page properties. PageTS is for Backend configuration! Enter this code in the Template Setup. Choose the Template module (from the menu on the left) and then navigate to the page, where you you want to add this. If there is no template yet, create a new extension template.

Comment: @StephenKing Exactly. I would probably just add it to the main (root) template; it can't hurt to have an identifier on the `<body>`. 
@Sven Koluem Do you use Templavoilà? I haven't tested that :-S

Comment: @Sven Koluem See update. This illustrates where to put the code. Hope you get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use TypoScript to add CSS rules (using page.cssInline) or additional CSS files (page.includeCSS). See [TSref](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.0/view/1/6/#id2630798), chapter for PAGE.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Typoscript Conditions](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/4/1/) to add/overwrite (css)files.
eg.

```
page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.value (

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fileadmin/js_css/style.css" />
)
#### add css to Page ID 1
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 1]
page.headerData.20 = TEXT
page.headerData.20.value (

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fileadmin/js_css/mycustomstyle.css" />
)
[end]
```

or a dirty but useful way to do so in backend is this little snippet. It uses the abtract field in your page properties where you can add some code into your `<head>`.

```
page.headerData.20 = TEXT
page.headerData.20.data = field:abstract
page.headerData.20.wrap =  |
```

Comment: I've edited my post. There was some german spelling inside, sorry. Make sure "page.headerData.20" is not used by any other object, otherwise the original one will be overwritten. And make sure you havent used your abstract field for anything else. Apart from that you can use this snippet, but dont forget to add a <style> tag inside your abstract field.

Comment: `page.headerData.60 = TEXT
page.headerData.60.data = field:abstract
page.headerData.60.wrap = <style >*{background-color:black !important;} </style>`

possible?

Comment: second question swould be can i post it directly into the tsconfig-field?

Comment: @1.question. No. The <pre>|</pre> is a divider for a wrap. Without a TS condition, it would affect your whole page. Put your CSS into the abstract field of your page properties, so it affects only your custom page.
@2.question: i never tried it.

Comment: ok i realise the dirty snippet, puts the style, which could be set in the abstract, to the page .. but where to put the snippet "page.headerD..."

Comment: Using page.includeCSS would be the clean way compared to page.headerData.